# Are the NetworkX minimum_cut algorithms correct with the following case?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm having a hard time trying to validate that the Python NetworkX library's max-flow min-cut algorithms work as expected (Edmonds-Karp, etc...). I don't know if I'm using it wrong or if my expectations on max-flow min-cut are mis-placed. Mostly I'm interested in how capacity (arc weights) affect the min-cut in larger graphs. e.g. influencing where cuts are made through arc weights.

The point of the capacity (arc weights) is a little lost on me. I've tried a cuople of different small graphs where all paths eventually converge on the target node, and in all cases the weight doesn't seem to really matter as the cut nodes/edges are always closest to the target node, where the smallest number of cuts applies. Maybe that's all this therom is trying to solve and I mis-understood its purpose.

Anyways, here's some code. The graph is super small and geared to playing with weights.

```
import networkx as nx # NetworkX v1.10
...
#   >a->e
#  /     \
# s->b->f->t
#  \     /
#   >c->g
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge("s", "a", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("s", "b", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("s", "c", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("a", "e", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("b", "f", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("c", "g", capacity=4)
G.add_edge("e", "t", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("f", "t", capacity=2)
G.add_edge("g", "t", capacity=4)

cut_nodes = nx.algorithms.connectivity.minimum_node_cut(G, "s", "t")
print "Cut nodes: " + str(cut_nodes)
# Always produces cuts for e, f, g

cut_edges = nx.algorithms.connectivity.minimum_edge_cut(G, "s", "t")
print "Cut edges: " + str(cut_edges)
# Always produces cuts for e->t, f->t, g->t
```

This is enough to play with the capacity numbers. What I'm not sure about is if the capacity is supposed to make a difference. I understand that a cut will be made, as long as s can reach t. If I adjust the capacity so path s->a->e->t has a capacity higher or lower between s->a, the same cut edges/nodes are always concluded.

The reason I'm asking openly about this is with NetworkX 0.8.1 I tried using the same support but specified the capacity edge attribute to be "weight" instead. The API wouldn't use it, even though the documentation supported the alternative label to base capacity on.

If capacity is supposed to affect what is cut in a graph like above, then this might be a NetworkX issue. I don't know.

Thanks for any enlightenment in advance!

**Update**

Thanks to Abdallah-Sobehy for pointing out that the minimum_node_cut and minimum_edge_cut methods onyl care about node cardinality. The problem I had I guess is documentation for minimum_edge_st_cut might be in correct when it says "NetworkX graph Edges of the graph are expected to have an attribute called 'capacity'. If this attribute is not present, the edge is considered to have infinite capacity"

Abdallah-Sobehy's code for determing the edge cuts works great. Another way to do it (referencing a bit of the NetworkX source) could be:

```
cut_edges = set()
for u, cn in ((n, G[n]) for n in partitions[0]):
    cut_edges.update((u, v) for v in cn if v in partitions[1])
```

I also wanted to try and find the nodes to be cut from the cut_edges. My understanding is node cuts are different from edge cuts, because the problems aren't the same. Something like edge weight (capacity) doesn't really matter to a node cut in the same way. (you'd want some node weight and consider cardinality)

Anyways, on this problem I'm looking at simply counting the dependent node in a cut edge (e.g. (node1 -> node2) as the node to cut, with some special handling for cut edges where the source and target are involved. It might work for me, but I'm not sure yet.

**Update 2 (final probably)**

I thought I would toss in my cut nodes based on cut edges code just for laughs.

```
cut_nodes = set()
for e in cut_edges:
    cut_nodes.update(e[1])
cut_st_nodes = set()
if s in cut_nodes or t in cut_nodes:
    for e in cut_edges:
        if e == (s, t):
            cut_st_nodes.update(t)
        elif e == (t, s):
            cut_st_nodes.update(t)
        elif t == e[1] or s == e[1]:
            cut_st_nodes.update(e[0])
cut_nodes -= set([s, t])
cut_nodes |= cut_st_nodes
```

The reasoning here, which might be wrong, is that all cut edges are directional and that the source node in the edge is dependent on the taret node in the edge, so removing the target node will reflect the edge cut. (e.g. n1 -> n2, n1 is dependent on n2, so remove n2) If this is true, then simply grabbing all target nodes from the cut edges will do, except if the graph source or target is involved. I have added cut_node_st to capture these type of cases where the source or target node is involved as an edge cut out bound target node. (e.g. n1 -> source, or n2 -> target)

I have cut_nodes_st separate from cut_nodes until the end because I only want s and t to appear in the cut_nodes when they're involved in those special cases.

Thoughts?

Comment: I posted a query to the NetworkX Github Issues section (https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1810) with another graph linked to an Emory U course that gives a nice explaination and example of the therom. Capacity never seems to affect the cut locations, and I can't reproduce the same cuts as in the example.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in your comment about the output of the functions, as you say minimum_node_cut always produces [d,f,e] but in the example you gave there is no "d" node to begin with. When I tried it it produced a node cit of **'e', 'g', 'f'**

Comment: You're right. I had to manually type this in. I'll correct it. BTW, thanks for following back to my Gitbuh post and replying there as well. :D

Comment: Oh it was you ! I did not notice that the comment is from the same as the asker  :D Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in your conclusion that changing the 'capacity' does not affect the outcome of the minimum_edge_cut and minimum_node_cut functions. But I believe that it is not an issue in Networkx as according to the documentation, those functions try to find the minimum cut in terms of cardinality (that is the smallest number of nodes/edges that if removed there will be no path between source and sink nodes). So, changing the capacity does not matter.

But recently I have wanted to do what you are pointing at. And I found the answer to be in the [minimum_cut](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.minimum_cut.html) function, where the documentation uses the max-flow min-cut theory and says clearly that capacity (or whatever attribute you choose) is taken into consideration to partition the graph into 2 set of nodes (each including either the s or t) where the **capacity of cutting edges** is minimum. And here playing with capacities values would yield different results.

The function returns **cut_value** that is the total capacity of all cutting edges, as well as **2 sets of nodes** each of them is a partition that contains the "s" or the "t" from which you can easily compute the edge_cut.

To clarify more, I added this part to your code:

```
cut_weight, partitions = nx.minimum_cut(G, "s", "t")
print "cut edges capacity " + str(cut_weight)
print "Set of nodes in the 's' partition: " + str(partitions[0])
print "Set of nodes in the 't' partition: " + str(partitions[1])
edge_cut_list = [] # Computed by listing edges between the 2 partitions
for p1_node in partitions[0]:
    for p2_node in partitions[1]:
        if G.has_edge(p1_node,p2_node):
            edge_cut_list.append((p1_node,p2_node))
print "Edges of the cut: " + str(edge_cut_list)
```

> The output yielded a total edge cut capacity of 6 which is less than the cut computed by minimum_edge_cut 8 (because it does not take edges weight into consideration.

```
cut edges capacity 6
Set of nodes in the 's' partition: set(['a', 's', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
Set of nodes in the 't' partition: set(['c', 't', 'g'])
Edges of the cut: [('s', 'c'), ('e', 't'), ('f', 't')]
```

Comment: Ha! Good catch. The documentation is very misleading. From minimum_st_edge_cut (which produces the same results as minimum_edge_cut): "Edges of the graph are expected to have an attribute called 'capacity'. If this attribute is not present, the edge is considered to have infinite capacity."

Comment: I've played with minimum_cut this morning and the results look reasonable. I came up with a bit of logic to determine the cut nodes, however and thought there would be a better way to do it. I won't ask about auxiliary graphs here, (I did on the networkx github) but would it be safe to simply take all target edge nodes as a set of node cuts? Then minus the source and target nodes from the set? I would need a special case where the target is one of the cut nodes, but it would work right?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question well. I think, in the general case it would work but not with minimum cardinality or capacity, it is just for the aim of disconnect. But another very interesting issue you raised [the special case] where source and the target are connected by an edge, in that case there should be no minimum_node_cut ! because you will have to remove the source or the target. And when I tried that on your graph (initializing it as an un-directed graph),minimum_node_cut(G,"c","g") gave "t" as the cut node !! Which if removed there will still be a path between the 2 nodes!

Comment: I suspect that, it is a bug in Networkx, do you know how can I report such thing, to be fixed or if I can fix it in the source code and submit it?

Comment: I have raised the issue here https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1812 but I wonder if I can do changes to the source code myself offering the solution ? If you know how, kindly let me know

Comment: Everything in NetworkX we've discussed is pretty close to the surface. If I was looking to fix minimum_node_cut in my own work, I would probably just implement my own minimum_node_cut with the changes based on the original source. However if you mean to submit a change to the Github project, you'll can always checkout the project into a branch, make the change, and submit it. I would contact the maintainers for guidance though. I can't seem to find a developers guide on how to test the library with any customizations. e.g. unittests